# Add taxes in the price filter - Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, filter, taxes

The prices of my products are added without taxes. The price filter that appears on my page is without taxes as you can see in the following picture

[image]

Is it possible to add taxes to this price filter?

Comment: Please add your code in which you are showing price in slider

Comment: This is a functionality of Magento

Comment: @Despotars, magento default does not provide price slider. I think you are using any module.

Comment: These filters are included with the theme that I bought, but the author does not give me support to change this. Any ideas on how you could add taxes to that filter?

Comment: You have to find the file and code when this layout is called and then you have to add price with text in it.

Comment: why do you need to put a tax in the price filter, I don't think it is necessary for a price filter.

Comment: Because I show the prices in my shop with taxes

Comment: Have you checked in luma theme the same issue is present is there? try to disable theme and see in blank theme.

Comment: verify your tax settings https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Show-price-including-taxes-in-catalog-product-page-show-price/m-p/131236#M7701

Comment: If you want to display the price with text then select the included text in the setting.
[![Slect inclusive tex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55FgF.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55FgF.png)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/159321)

Comment: I think now it's fine

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/159332)

Comment: What about the screen shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should locate the class that shows the filter and add the tax rule class that you have created, with this you would solve your problem

Comment: At which file i need to add my Tax class rule in phtml file?